# Executing the same rule for two diffrent cases in prolog

Tags: prolog

Assume I have this predicate:

```
parentheses2([H1,'+'|T],L,C).
parentheses2([H1,'-'|T],L,C) :- L=[1,2,3].
parentheses2([H1,'*'|T],L,C).
parentheses2([H1,'/'|T],L,C) :- L=[1,2,4,5,6,9].
```

What I want to achievie is to get the same answer when i ask prolog `?-parentheses2([1,-,3],L,5).` and `?- parentheses2([1,+,3],L,5).`, without rewritting `L=[1,2,3]` into `parentheses2([H1,'+'|T],L,C)`. I want to make Prolog execute `L=[1,2,3]` in two diffrent cases (when there is '+' or '-' after `H1`). The reasoning behind it is that in place `L=[1,2,3]`, `L=[1,2,4,5,6,9]` I'd like to put more complex rules.
Is there any way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean

```
parentheses2([H1,Op|T],L,C) :- ( Op = '+' ; Op = '-' ), L=[1,2,3].
```